# Нет отступа у абзаца?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет есть такой вот код.

```css
.headerP{
  color:#6d6d6d;
  font-size:18px;
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.cityP{
  color:#000000;
  font-size:16px;
  margin-left:130px;
}
```

```html
<p class="headerP">Все медицинские учреждения вашего города</p>
<p class="cityP">Алматы</p>
```

Принтскрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему слово Алматы прилипло вплотную, когда есть свойсто margin-left. И как выравнить два абзаца по вертикали а то видно что "Алматы" стоит чуть выше?

Answer (score 1):

Птому что там отступы в em'ах и размер шрифта разный. Надо так:

```css
.header, .city {
  float: left;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 18px 0;
}

.header {
  color: #6d6d6d;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.city {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}
```

```html
<p class="header">Все медицинские учреждения вашего города</p>
<p class="city">Алматы</p>
```